# Sublime Text Editor 3, Mac, Icon Missing

Tags: macos, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I was playing around with Sublime Text Editor 3 (trying some themes, linters etc). After I restarted my MacBook (OSX Mavericks), the icon is missing from both the dock and the applications folder.

I tried to remove it(uninstall it, remove from applications folder) and also deleted all files in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3` and `~/Library/Preferences/Sublime Text 3` and then re-install (fresh download) but still nothing. The icons won't show in the dock neither in the applications folder.

I checked and after the whole procedure any packages, themes etc are not there which means that I'm successfully removing every file of it before i re-install it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a clean install of Sublime Text 3 and restarting, the icon came back.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "clean install".
In my case, I uninstalled, then reinstalled, icon didn't come back.
Then I installed it again (without uninstalling), choosing to "Replace" it in the Applications. Only then did the icon return. All of my packages and open files were kept as it is.